# Get only rows with max value having 5 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT work_orders.id,work_orders.create_datetime,work_orders.location,
       work_orders.description,user_accounts.function as function,
       user_accounts.name as username,work_order_states.name as state,
       work_orders_history.state_id,max(work_order_states.id)
FROM `work_orders`
LEFT JOIN work_orders_history 
    on work_orders.id = work_orders_history.work_order_id
LEFT JOIN user_accounts 
    on work_orders.create_user_id = user_accounts.id
LEFT JOIN work_order_type 
    on work_orders_history.type_id = work_order_type.id
LEFT JOIN work_order_states 
    on work_orders_history.state_id = work_order_states.id
```

... and the result is this:
[image]

But what i want is only get the rows with max `state_id`.

I already tried various queries, but this is the best result I can get.

EDIT: Since it's more than 65k results it's hard to provide a fiddle. The desireable result is like this image:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A sample dataset (e.g. an sqlfiddle) and a desired result would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be very close in your query.  You need to add a GROUP BY and take away one of your select columns.

```
SELECT work_orders.id,work_orders.create_datetime,work_orders.location,
       work_orders.description,user_accounts.[function] as [function],
       user_accounts.name as username,work_order_states.name as state,
       max(work_order_states.id)
FROM `work_orders`
LEFT JOIN work_orders_history 
    on work_orders.id = work_orders_history.work_order_id
LEFT JOIN user_accounts 
    on work_orders.create_user_id = user_accounts.id
LEFT JOIN work_order_type 
    on work_orders_history.type_id = work_order_type.id
LEFT JOIN work_order_states 
    on work_orders_history.state_id = work_order_states.id

GROUP BY work_orders.id,work_orders.create_datetime,work_orders.location,
       work_orders.description,user_accounts.function,
       user_accounts.name,work_order_states.name
HAVING work_orders_states.ID = (SELECT MAX(state_id) FROM work_orders_history)
```

Comment: good teamwork, you for the grouping. and then just add the having clause to select only the max records. thanks...

Comment: this query gives me the same result i have

Comment: My apologies.  I just saw your expected code.  Do you want only records for the highest stateID that is available in your work_order_states table or for the highest stateID that is available in your work_orders_history table?

Comment: I'm looking for the highest stateID that is available in your work_orders_history table.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the HAVING and GROUP BY clause combined..

```
SELECT work_orders.id,work_orders.create_datetime,work_orders.location,
       work_orders.description,user_accounts.function as function,
       user_accounts.name as username,work_order_states.name as state,
       work_orders_history.state_id,max(work_order_states.id)
FROM `work_orders`
LEFT JOIN work_orders_history 
    on work_orders.id = work_orders_history.work_order_id
LEFT JOIN user_accounts 
    on work_orders.create_user_id = user_accounts.id
LEFT JOIN work_order_type 
    on work_orders_history.type_id = work_order_type.id
LEFT JOIN work_order_states 
    on work_orders_history.state_id = work_order_states.id

GROUP BY work_orders.id,work_orders.create_datetime,work_orders.location,
       work_orders.description,user_accounts.function,
       user_accounts.name,work_order_states.name,
       work_orders_history.state_id

HAVING work_orders_history.state_id=max(work_order_states.id)
```

Comment: This query will not run due to having 'AS XXXX' in the GROUP BY section.  Those need to come off and then it will run.

Comment: this query gives an error (Unknown column 'work_order_states.id' in 'having clause')